# A 2º button doesn't appear under my first one

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Using Wordpress, I don't know why but I try to put a button under another one but it doesn't appear. I tried changing the name of my classes and other stuff, and still having the same problem. Here's my code:

```
<style>

#body2{
width: 343px;
height: 1094px;
background-image:url("/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/der-side.png");
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:cover;
 background-position: left top;
}

.myButton {
    background-color:transparent;
    border:3px solid #000000;
        margin-top: 923px;
        margin-left: 75px;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#000000;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:18px;
    padding:16px 47px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.myButton:hover {
    background-color:black;
        text-decoration: none;
}
.myButton:active {
    position:relative;
text-decoration: none;
}

.per{
    background-color:transparent;
    border:3px solid #000000;
        margin-top: 953px;
        margin-left: 75px;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#000000;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:18px;
    padding:16px 47px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.per:hover {
    background-color:black;
        text-decoration: none;
}
.per:active {
    position:relative;
        text-decoration: none;
}

</style>


<div id="body2">

<div><a href="http://en.calameo.com/read/001102166473a9789fb8a" class="myButton" target="_blank">C A T Á L O G O</a></div>

<div><a href="/personaliza-una-brompton/" class="per" target="_blank">Personaliza</a></div>
</div>
```

What could it be? CSS?

Comment: the site http://centralbike.albeh.com.mx/brompton/

Comment: that margin top of 953px is the culprit, should be easy to spot if you inspect the code in your developer tools.